# scp from distant host to local server in a script

Tags: shell, ssh, command-line, scp

I have been able to find lots of examples of server hopping and ProxyCommand but none relating to my specific need.

I want to transfer a file from a distant server to a local server. Currently, I can ssh from `local` to `jump` and from `jump` to `distant` (can not ssh from local to distant directly). Then from `distant` I can scp a file back to `local`. Right now I do this manually:

from local: `ssh userJ@jump`

then from jump: `ssh userD@distant`

then from distant: `scp \path\file userL@local:\dest\path\`

But I want to be able to do this in a script that I run from local. I have rsh keys stored in the appropriate places to eliminate password prompts. I just can't figure out the syntax for a single command.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to "push" the files on `distant` back to `local`?

It'd be easier to simply "pull" the files while on `local` from `distant`.

Setup `~/.ssh/config` on `local`:

```
[userL@local]# cat ~/.ssh/config
Host distant
HostName Distant
user userD
ProxyCommand ssh -A userJ@jump nc %h %p
```

Test the connection using ssh:

```
[userL@local]# ssh -A userD@distant    [or even:  ssh -A distant]
Last login: Tue Oct 23 16:05:59 2018 from jump
[userD@distant]#
```

Now pull a file from `distant`:

```
[userL@local]# scp userD@distant:/distantpath/distantfile /localpath/localfile
distantfile                100%  129KB 128.9KB/s   00:01
[userL@local]#
```

In the example above, I used ssh's agent forwarding to pass credentials from `local` to `jump` and ultimately `distant`.  You just need to pre-populate the authorized keys on `jump` and `distant` before agent forwarding will work.

Answer (score 0):

I usually address this by configuring my ssh client in the `~/.ssh/config` file to do the jump automatically:

```
Host distant-jump
  User userD
  Hostname distant
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p jump

Host jump
  User userJ
```

Then you can just: `scp distant-jump:/path/file ./`